# Android make a screen disable or unclickable

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make my android activity unclickable. I have tried [Enable/disable an activity programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493947/enable-disable-an-activity-programatically) but it's not working for me.

I also tried to get relative layout disable but it is not working.

Is there any other ways for making and android activity(full) unclickable?

Comment: No , You need to make your views unclickable one by one :)

Comment: @Mahfa I have around 25 button. So i have to manually make every button disable.

Comment: as i know , yes and it isn't hard to do that ! :)

Comment: @Mahfa moveTaskToBack(true);"Hide" current Activity and sent to background. Do you know any other function where it's don't sent to background just make it disable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a fake transparent view which takes up with whole screen and place it on top of all views.

```
private boolean shouldBlockTouches = false;

fakeView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return shouldBlockTouches;
        }
    });
```

set the shouldBlockTouches where ever you please.

Answer (score 2):

You could set every view as unclickable in the XML:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: Yes, but could you provide alternative solution to make this from java code and on button click not from XML.

Comment: Sure, try using setEnabled(false) on each button.  That should make them unclickable as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can try by applying onClick on root layout and do nothing.tou can do this as well
if u want activity unclickable then doesn't provide any beahvior will tend to do nothing.