# enable/disable packages programmatically

Tags: android, android-package-managers

How can I enable/disable a whole **package** programmatically from a **Android System application**?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494124/4038549) post, a component is enabled/disabled programmatically, but not a whole package.

I want to achieve the same result that is achieved by the root command `pm disable/enable package_name` (from the adb shell -> su).

Comment: You could try running the same command programatically.  It would obviously only work on a rooted device.

Comment: Why do you need a rooted device? You would just need a system privileged application.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this:

1. Using pm disable command:

   ```
   Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
   runtime.exec("pm disable "+packageName);
   ```
2. Using PackageManager api:

   ```
   public abstract void setApplicationEnabledSetting (String packageName, 
                                                      int newState, int flags)
   ```

Where, in newState param you can pass "COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED" to disable the app & "COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED" to enable the app.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#setApplicationEnabledSetting(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)