# Difference between disabling package vs disabling activity using package manager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-package-managers, android-components

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494124/6680585) shows an example of disabling an activity. But in few places I've seen disabling package completely.

1. Disabling activity

> ```
> PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); 
> pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, 
>         com.packagename.MyActivity.class), 
>         PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
>         PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
> ```

2. Disabling a package

> ```
> PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); 
> pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, 
>         com.packagename), 
>         PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
>         PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
> ```

What is the difference between disabling a package vs disabling an activity? Does disabling a component means it would disable all classes within the package?

Answer (score 3):

Disabling component will disable only that class . 
Disabling package will disable complete application . You can assume this as disabling all components inside Manifest & process will no more be running in this case since complete application is disabled .